# Copied data paste into String function

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone tell me how to store copied data into `String` in selenium?

example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="x")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="xy")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="xy")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

I need put the copied data into String

Something like this

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="xy")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code.  First, you don't send multiple keys as parameters to sendKeys, it would be `Keys.Control + "a"` for example, but even then, you're doing a control-v (paste) to the same element that you're copying from, which does effectively nothing.  No, you can't sendKeys to a variable other than one of type WebElement, not string.  Lastly, why don't you just assign the `getText()` value to a string, then you can use that to sendKeys to the desired WebElement.

Comment: I also just noticed that your second xpath is doing a copy from a different WebElement, not the one that received the control-a.  Those are probably just typos, but it still is not the way to go about what you're trying to accomplish.  Keep it simple.

Comment: One last comment - if the WebElement is an input type, then instead of `getText()` you'd probably want to use `getAttribute('Value')`

Comment: Hi Bill, Actually I wanted to store copied data in string, assume that I have copied data from one text box and I need to store into string for data compare

Comment: Is the copied data from an input control, like a textbox?  If so, you can simply use Selenium's .getAttribute("Value") to get the string value and assign that to a string variable.  If the WebElement is capable of accepting input via sendKeys then its value should be accessible from getAttribute.  If you absolutely -have- to test a copy/paste then it can be accomplished, I suppose, but not by assigning it to a String variable, only by pasting the contents of the clipboard by doing the sendKeys of control-v to the destination input element, but that seems like a strange way to go about it.

Comment: @Starlord , I think you have to see how to use the getText()
it automatically store the fetched value to string , you just have to define it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to send `ctrl + c` keys, which will copy some data in clipboard.. want to store that data in String variable..right?

You have to use Clipboard class to do so..See implementation below...

```
package resources;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class One {

    @Test
    public void getClipboardContents() {
        String result = "";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        String copy = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.chord("c")); 
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).sendKeys(copy);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        if (hasTransferableText) {
            try {
                result = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

@Starlord ..modify locators as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

@Gaurav Thanks for the code.. I have modified some part of the code.. now I am getting what i want exactly

```
public void getClipboardContents() 
throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
String result = "google.com";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
String copy = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.chord("c"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys("google.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"a");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]")).sendKeys(copy);

Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
String x = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
System.out.println(x);
int a= result.length();
int b = x.length();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
if(a<=b) 
{
System.out.println("Matched Character length")
}else 
{
 System.out.println("Issue In Character length");
}
 }

    }
```